# Anyone have recommendations on data collection system for bird point counts?

Tags: arcpad, wildlife-ecology

We will be conducting point counts this spring and summer, and would like to move away from paper data entry forms (yeah, I know).  I have spent a little time exploring ArcPad (10), there are significant bugs (using "Find" to get to a point doesn't work, data transfer is unreliable, etc).

At each point, we will need to capture a GPS location (one record in a table of points), then will record observations for birds at the associated point (one record per bird in a table of observations).  The once nice thing about ArcPad is that it's easy to set up the one-to-many relationship between points and observations, and enter as many observations as needed.  But I'm just too nervous sending crews out to collect a few weeks' worth of data without feeling 100% confident we'll get the data back.  Also, the Trimble units are too expensive, and the screens are just too small for easy data entry.

I was wondering whether anyone had explored options using Android tablets, or something similar, for data collection in the field...?  In the past, I used a Trimble data collection unit with Pocket Excel.  This kind of system would work, but the one-to-many link depends upon the user entering a point ID correctly in both the point table and the observation table.  I like the idea of a cheap Android tablet with 3 or 4g connectivity running an app that allows data collection in this manner, and would be fine sending crews out with a separate handheld GPS, if accuracy is too poor with a tablet.

Would really appreciate any ideas or suggestions for data collection.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider [EpiCollect](http://www.epicollect.net/). I don't have much experience with it, so I cannot strongly recommend it, but it might meet your needs. Some of it's advantages are:

- it's free
- allows you to build customized data entry forms
- runs on Android
- and it appears you can customize the interface to collect data with a [one-to-many relationship](http://www.epicollect.net/plus/Instructions/developers/ecml/forms_hierarchy.html).

Hope that helps.